# can't upload the picture in firestorage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

So, I am trying to make a website like fb or insta, it needs to upload the picture during signup, the email, password, name got into authentication smoothly but the profile pic did not. I am thinking my syntax might be of older version.

here, are some snippets:

```
import { AuthContext } from '../Context/AuthContext';
import { databse, storage} from '../firebase';
.
.
.

const handleClick=async()=>{
        if(file==null){
            setError("please upload a profile picture")
            setTimeout(()=>{
                setError('')
            },2000)
            return;
        }
        try{
            setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            let userObj=await signup(email,password)
            let uid=userObj.user.uid;
            console.log(uid)
            const uploadTask=storage.ref(`/users/${uid}/ProfileImage`).put(file);
            uploadTask.on('state_changed', fn1, fn2, fn3) //fn1 will run when progress,,, fn2 when error, fn3 when successful
            function fn1(snapshot){
               .....
            }
        
            function fn3(){
                uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
                    console.log(url)
                    databse.users.doc(uid).set({
                        email: email,
                        userId:uid,
                        fullname:name,
                        profileUrl:url,
                        // createdAt: databse.getTimeStamp()
                    })
                })
                setLoading(false);
                console.log("done")
            }
        }catch(err){
            setError(err)
            setTimeout(()=>{
                setError('')
            },2000)
            return;

        }
    }
.
.
.
.
.

   <input type='file' accept='image/*' hidden onChange={(e)=>setFile(e.target.files[0])}/>
```

error shown is "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Answer (score 1):

This is how I recently uploaded images to my fire storage other day if this helps in any way:

```
//img file
const [profileIcon, setProfileIcon] = useState<ArrayBuffer>();

//change img to arrayBuffer
const changeFile = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>{
   if(e.target.files){
        e.target.files[0]?.arrayBuffer().then((res)=>setProfileIcon(res));
            // setProfileIcon(e.target.files[0])
            setImgName(e.target.files[0].name);
        }
    }
//upload img and update user
const metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

if(profileIcon != undefined){
   const uploadSnapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef,profileIcon,metadata);
 
   const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(uploadSnapshot.ref);
    
   await updateProfile(user.user, {
     displayName: `${data.FirstName} ${data.LastName}`,
     photoURL: downloadUrl,
    });
}
```